# Implement different disqus shortnames in Opencart

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, opencart, disqus

I'm using opencart 1.5.5.1.
On the products pages I've already successfully changed the "Review" tab with a discussion tool by [Disqus](http://disqus.com/)! and it works great.
But my website is dual language italian/english and I would like the users to read the discussion in the language they've chosen. 
So I've created two differents disqus id's (two independent discussion boards).

On my product.tpl I had to insert their javascript that comes with a variable like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */

var disqus_shortname = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
```

I would like to make the variable disqus_shortname to depend on language code given on the session.

As long as I understand I can get it by php with

```
$this->session->data['language']
```

or

```
$this->language->get('code')
```

but here we are talking about js!
How can I tell this script the statement if?
I need something like

```
if $this->language->get('code') == 'it' { var disqus_shortname = 'xxxxxxxxxxitalian'; }
else { var disqus_shortname = 'xxxxxxxxxxenglish'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you register a disqus shortname for your website on Disqus.

> disqus_shortname
>
> Tells the Disqus service your forum's shortname, which is the unique
>   identifier for your website as registered on Disqus. If undefined, the
>   Disqus embed will not load.

To load different language on the page,use

```
var disqus_config = function () { 
  this.language = "ru";
};
```

code like:

```
 <?php
    $language = ( $this->language->get('code') == 'it' )? 'it' : 'en';
    ?>
    <script>
    var disqus_config = function () { 
          this.language = "<?php echo $language; ?>";
        };
```

http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466249-can-disqus-be-loaded-in-different-languages-per-page-

Comment: maybe I haven't explain my problem properly.
I already have two disqus_shortname because I want to keep the english and italian discussions separated.

So, what I need to do is to create a condition that chose the right disqus_shortname depending on the language of the session.

Comment: what I want to avoid is to have mixed english/italian comments on the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

In Your controller You would have to propagate the language code to the template (edit `catalog/controller/product/product.php` file) - add this:

```
$this->data['language_code'] = $this->language->get('code');
```

Then edit the template file this way (`catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/product/product.tpl`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */

var disqus_shortname = 'xxxxxxxxxx<?php echo $language_code; ?>'; // here the mojo is done...

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
(function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script');
    dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you both for tour replies. I've actually already achieved what I needed setting the 'code'$language = ( $this->language->get('code') == 'it' )? 'it' : 'en';'code' and then using it on the script for the condition to set the two disqus_shortnames.
I would show you the code but I cannot reply my same question...

Comment: @FabrizioTatti You can answer Your own question and if You realized Your own solution You should even post and accept it here. Anyway, in OpenCart, the condition `$lang = ($this->language->get('code') == 'it' ? 'it' : 'en');` is the very same as if You called only `$lang = $this->language->get('code');`...